# Find the stationary points of $f(x,y,z)= xy+yz+xz$ subject to the constraint $x+y+z-3=0$

Tags: partial-derivative, lagrange-multiplier, constraints, stationary-processes

So far this is what I have done:

$F(x,y,z)= (xy+yz+xz) + λ(x+y+z-3)$

> $Fx = (y+z)+λ=0$
>
> $Fy = (x+z)+λ=0$
>
> $Fz = (y+x)+λ=0$
>
> $Fλ = (x+y+z-3)=0$

I found that $x,y$ and $z$ are $1$ and $λ$ is $-2$

I'm not sure what to do after this.

Comment: If your calculations are correct, the only stationary point is $(x,y,z) = ( 1,1,1)$.

Answer (score 1):

Let's call the constraint equation $g $, so $g=x+y+z-3$ and we're looking at the level curve $g=0$. By Lagrange multipliers were looking for when the system
$$\nabla F=\lambda \nabla g$$
$$g=0$$
Is satisfied. Expanded out that is
$$y+z=\lambda$$
$$x+z=\lambda$$
$$y+x=\lambda $$
$$x+y+z-3=0$$
And from there it's just a matter of solving that system for $(x,y,z) $ which satisfies it and those points will be your stationary/critical points.
By simply looking at this system we can gather that $x=y=z$. Using that, the equation $g=0$ tells us that $3x-3=0$ which shows $x=1$, and therefore $(1,1,1) $ satisfies the system and is a critical point.
The work you had done is correct all you have to remember is the solutions to the system of equation you created are the critical points: Just make sure they make sense and you're done.